# solution to prevent java application from being reverse engineered- maybe some form of encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I want a java desktop application to be encrypted/some mechanism to ensure that it is not reverse engineered.

Any pointers in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean like these? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=solution+to+prevent+java+application+from+being+reverse+engineered  The problem with encryption is you have to be able to decrypt it automagically to run the code.  Obfuscation is usually the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. [See this for the full details](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html). This has been a long-running problem with Java, about as old as the language itself.

Comment: It's a problem with any language, but it is a bit more visible for managed languages such as Java (which by now is almost any language except unmanaged C/C++). I won't even include scripting languages. Interesting link!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for "obfuscation".
This kind of technique will make any type of reverse engineering a lot harder by "rearranging" the generated bytecode. Sometimes this also comes with a bonus performance increase since the obfuscator can take the time to optimize the bytecode.
Take a look at tools such as [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) and [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.htm).

Answer (score 0):

At a prior company, we used DashO with success.  http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho

Understand, though, that you're opening a can of worms, to some extent.  Understanding where the code died from a stack trace will not be simple...the method names and variables are all obfuscated, and so stack traces are meaningless without the mapping file DashO produced for that specific build.